# angular-ui typeahead batarang conflict?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, batarang

I am using ui-bootstrap 0.11.2 on angular 1.2.25 and chased this all morning until I came across a somewhat unrelated post that provided some hints.

My use of the ui-angular typeahead directive stopped working in Chrome. Specifically, it would not fill in the data field when the user selected an item from the dropdown list.  I could get the debugger to stop in 'selectActive', but it was not calling 'selectMatch'.

I read a bunch of the threads about typeahead being broken on earlier versions due to the use of 'ng-if' vs. 'ng-show', but the version I am using appears to have this fixed.

I then saw a thread related to (new??) messages from hint.js, which I am seeing for the first time, and someone suggested disabling the batarang plugin to address that issue.

Sure enough, I disabled batarang and the issue with typeahead went away.

It appears that batarang was updated yesterday, which I assume was why I started seeing these new messages and this issue.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems with angular directives and batarang?  I would like to confirm that this was the source of the issue and not just misdirection at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Batarang maintainer here.  So long as you're using the latest version of Batarang (`0.8.7`), you should be good.  Please note that the so-called "Batarang Stable" plugin is not related to the Batarang project (and an old version of Batarang to boot).  If you're on "Stable", please install the official version and your issues should be resolved.